# What to do about obvious copyright violations or cut/paste answers?

Tags: discussion, copyright, plagiarism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with questions or answers plagiarism  from copyrighted sources?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19508/how-to-deal-with-questions-or-answers-plagiarism-from-copyrighted-sources)

What should be done when someone answers a question by simply cutting and pasting text from somewhere else online?

[Example Answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/64484/whats-the-difference-between-ssl-and-tls/64542#64542)

[Original Text](http://kb.iu.edu/data/anjv.html)

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19508/how-to-deal-with-questions-or-answers-plagiarism-from-copyrighted-sources

Answer (score 5):

If you have edit power edit it.  Otherwise, flag it for moderator attention.  Make sure you give them the original URL so they can edit the source into the answer.

Comment: @Jinguy: I believe it is a serious violation because the copyright levels are different between the websites. They aren't necessarily compatible. So if text or code sample is 'copy/paste with attribution only' and then you paste it somewhere that is 'copy/paste reuse at will' you are changing the 'access level'.

Comment: Yeah, I got rid of that part after reading the copyright of knowledge base.

Comment: No, don't flag it. Moderators can't really do anything.  See my answer at this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19508/how-to-deal-with-questions-or-answers-plagiarism-from-copyrighted-sources/19521#19521

Comment: If enough people flag it as abuse (vs. for moderator intervention), the problem will just silently go away...

Comment: What if we flag it with a link ot the source?  It is basically like editing it in yourself, but through a moderator.

Comment: Read my answer at the link: just because there's a copyright violation doesn't mean we can just delete it.  It might even turn out to be the original author posting with a pseudonym, or it might be the author _wants_ their content up on stackoverflow where ever possible.

Comment: Flagging with a link is a little better, at least.