# What is proper etiquette when someone posts copyrighted material?

Tags: discussion, flags, copyright, legal

I just ran into an answer in which the author included a link to a PDF book that was licensed only to them. I'm pretty sure this is copyrighted material and the author does not want copies of the book to be freely available on the web.

What is the proper etiquette in this situation? Leave a comment? (I can't yet, I just joined.) Mark as offensive? Contact a moderator?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be in the [community FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/), but needs some formatting changes to be incorporated.  (Post it as a new question following the guidelines on the FAQ index.)

Comment: Related but not dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21938/questions-with-proprietary-or-confidential-information

Comment: Although a newer question, the answers over at [What should I do when I see copyright violations posted on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114919/138432) are more useful and comprehensive than the answer here, especially the one by [Robert Harvey♦](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114928/138432)

Answer (score 11):

1. If you don't have the rights to post it, don't.
2. If you do have the rights to post it, attribute it appropriately
3. If you don't have rights to post it, but it's publicly available (legally) elsewhere, it's okay to *link* to it — but you should also summarize it (in your own words) and attribute it

If you find content that is infringing, I suggest you read this:

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19521/3043