# Copying Area 51 example questions from one proposal to another

Tags: discussion, area-51

In the Area 51 site proposal [Agile Software Development](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16601/agile-software-development) four example questions are copied from elsewhere.

Three are copied from Area 51 site proposal [Scrum](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7794/scrum) and one from an external source (though it is now only in the Google cache and probably covered by "[How to deal with questions or answers plagiarism from copyrighted sources?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19508/how-to-deal-with-questions-or-answers-plagiarism-from-copyrighted-sources)").

But what do you think about copying within Area 51? For example, is it acceptable with the right attribution?

---

**Update**: sometimes [copies are downvoted](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10919/lego/16508#16508) (as "not a good example").

Comment: Please tag Area 51 questions as [area51]

Answer (score 2):

If they're applicable to each proposal I don't see any problem with it.  I don't see that an issue of plagiarism exists in the proposal phase.  That wouldn't happen until you get into at least Beta when questions are getting answered.  How can you copyright a question?

Comment: I suspect, technically, any question that is long enough for the "originality" and other criteria would be copyrightable. I suspect it'd have to push into more than one paragraph, though-