# Providing someone else’s answer

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with questions or answers plagiarising from copyrighted sources](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19508/how-to-deal-with-questions-or-answers-plagiarising-from-copyrighted-sources)

I have found an answer to a question, which is exact copy and paste from an answer which some else provide in another website.

There was no reference to the original answer and the user provided the answer pretending like he/she made that answer.

Is it always the best way to provide answers?

Isn’t it some kind of plagiarism?

Should answers are reference to the originals?

Comment: I always edit them to include a link to the original reference and put the copypaste in a blockquote (along with an explanatory comment in the edit comment field to let the user do the same in the future). I never upvote them afterwards, though.

Comment: How do you know that the person didn't cite himself?

Comment: If the answer is taken from another site, it should probably be removed, or replaced with a link *to* the original, perhaps adding some context as to how this helps/relates. It does nobody any favors keeping plagiarised content.

Answer (score 6):

With the number of dupes we have on the sites, it's sometimes the best way to provide answers, **BUT** they should always be attributed in some way.  It should always be clear who created the answer.