# Should the content of answers found on non-SE sites be copied to SE or linked to?

Tags: discussion, copyright

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

I have seen answers to questions which consist of a brief summary (i.e. not able to stand alone) and a link to another site. If that site ever goes away, the in-depth version of the answer will be lost.

Should original content found on other sites that sufficiently answers the question be copied/rewritten/etc onto the SE site and referenced?

Comment: You will find a lot of reasoning there. In general, yes. Link-rot is evil, and we should provide any necessary information here.

Comment: @slhck Thanks for the link. That answers part of my question. I guess the other part relates to copyright and how much should get transferred from the other site. Should I edit my question to change the emphasis?

Comment: Please do so. I'm sure this has been discussed already.

Comment: [How to deal with questions or answers plagiarising from copyrighted sources?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19508/how-to-deal-with-questions-or-answers-plagiarising-from-copyrighted-sources), et al.  @agf The SE people want external content cited regardless from everything I've heard. Users shouldn't have to make distinctions like that anyways; very few are knowledgable enough, as well.

Comment: It's a complicated question. If the other site has a compatible license or a public domain notice, just copy enough for it to stand alone. If it's an incompatible license or "all rights reserved" then you need to follow fair use -- which is an amorphous concept at best.

Comment: @MatthewRead I don't think the question has anything to do with whether or not to cite. It's about can you copy content / how much should you copy / etc. _in addition_ to citing the source.