# Excerpts from Published Works in Questions and Answers

Tags: discussion, support, copyright

Sometimes, a question or answer would benefit greatly from an excerpt in a published work, like a textbook, novel, journal, magazine, or website. How much can one post from the published work in a question or answer, if any, and how should they be cited?

Comment: Are the rules similar to those used in the classroom? http://copyright.lib.utexas.edu/clasguid.html

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113559/quoting-content-from-external-sites-is-this-considered-fair-use